# Installed Ubuntu 22.04 on a Dell Inspiron N411Z and now it can't find the OS

Tags: boot, 22.04, dell, rufus

I tried to install Ubuntu on a Dell Inspiron N411Z, as the only OS, deleting the Windows 7 it had on it. The installation finished correctly, and it prompted me to restart the computer. When restarted, a message shows up saying Operation System not found, and it takes me to the BIOS menu. I used Rufus 3.21.1949 portable to create a bootable USB. (My USB being 7.8 GB). I tried with a MBR and with a GPT partition, and neither worked.

It's the first time I tried installing an OS. Do you have any idea what might have gone wrong?

Here are some images of the Bios:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3l37k.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ci7fN.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qi0fa.jpg)
[boot settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vjtx.jpg)

Comment: Rufus settings are unrelated. If you could boot from USB and successfully install Ubuntu, then the LiveUSB is OK. The problem can be in BIOS settings. Did you set the device to boot from. And is it an UEFI or BIOS mode?

Comment: I have added some pictures of the bios settings. Is there anything wrong there?

Comment: You didn't add the Boot one.

Comment: Sorry, @Pilot6 now I added them. But the only setting possible is changing the order of execution.

Comment: if your system boots from the usb and you click on try ubuntu what happens? you can remove the picture of rufus from your question if the usb installer works.

Comment: If I click try ubuntu, it works fine.

Comment: Please download the [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) tool. It may be able to fix the problem more-or-less automatically; and if not, it can generate a report (called the "Boot-Info Summary") and upload it to a pastebin site. Give us the link to that summary and we'll be better able to advise you on how to proceed. At this point there are more unknowns than knowns about your installation, and a Boot-Info Summary will help fill in some of the important unknowns.